# Memoizing a function of type [Integer] -> a

Tags: haskell, memoization

My problem is how to efficiently memoize an expensive function `f :: [Integer] -> a` that is defined for all *finite* lists of integers and has the property `f . sort = f`?

My typical use case is that given a list `as` of integers I need to obtain the values `f (a:as)` for various Integer a, so I'd like to build up simultaneously a directed labelled graph whose vertices are pairs of an Integer list and its function value. An edge labelled by a from (as, f as) to (bs, f bs) exists if and only if a:as = bs.

Stealing from a [brilliant answer by Edward Kmett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209189/99978) I simply copied

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
data Tree a = Tree (Tree a) a (Tree a)
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Tree l m r) = Tree (fmap f l) (f m) (fmap f r)

index :: Tree a -> Integer -> a
index (Tree _ m _) 0 = m
index (Tree l _ r) n = case (n - 1) `divMod` 2 of
  (q,0) -> index l q
  (q,1) -> index r q

nats :: Tree Integer
nats = go 0 1
  where go !n !s = Tree (go l s') n (go r s')
          where l = n + s
                r = l + s
                s' = s * 2
```

and adapted his idea to my problem as

```
-- directed graph labelled by Integers
data Graph a = Graph a (Tree (Graph a))
instance Functor Graph where
  fmap f (Graph a t) = Graph (f a) (fmap (fmap f) t)

-- walk the graph following the given labels
walk :: Graph a -> [Integer] -> a
walk (Graph a _) [] = a
walk (Graph _ t) (x:xs) = walk (index t x) xs

-- graph of all finite integer sequences
intSeq :: Graph [Integer]
intSeq = Graph [] (fmap (\n -> fmap (n:) intSeq) nats)

-- could be replaced by Data.Strict.Pair
data StrictPair a b = StrictPair !a !b
  deriving Show

-- f = sum modified according to Edward's idea (the real function is more complicated)
g :: ([Integer] -> StrictPair Integer [Integer]) -> [Integer] -> StrictPair Integer [Integer]
g mf [] = StrictPair 0 []
g mf (a:as) = StrictPair (a+x) (a:as)
  where StrictPair x y = mf as

g_graph :: Graph (StrictPair Integer [Integer])
g_graph = fmap (g g_m) intSeq

g_m :: [Integer] -> StrictPair Integer [Integer]
g_m = walk g_graph
```

This works OK, but as the function `f` is independent of the order of the occurring integers (but not of their counts) there should be only one vertex in the graph for all integer lists equal up to ordering.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Memoizing is a thing... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization Please don't edit it to "memorize"

Comment: Are all of the elements of the list non-negative?

Comment: @Cirdec: Yes! (Sorry for forgetting to mention it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the functional pearl [Trouble Shared is Trouble Halved](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/HW03.pdf) by Richard Bird and Ralf Hinze, I understood how to implement, what I was looking for two years ago (again based on Edward Kmett's trick):

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Data.Function (fix)

data Tree a = Tree (Tree a) a (Tree a)
  deriving Show

instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Tree l m r) = Tree (fmap f l) (f m) (fmap f r)

index :: Tree a -> Integer -> a
index (Tree _ m _) 0 = m
index (Tree l _ r) n = case (n - 1) `divMod` 2 of
  (q,0) -> index l q
  (q,1) -> index r q

nats :: Tree Integer
nats = go 0 1
  where go !n !s = Tree (go l s') n (go r s')
          where l = n + s
                r = l + s
                s' = s * 2

data IntSeqTree a = IntSeqTree a (Tree (IntSeqTree a))

val :: IntSeqTree a -> a
val (IntSeqTree a _) = a

step :: Integer -> IntSeqTree t -> IntSeqTree t
step n (IntSeqTree _ ts) = index ts n

intSeqTree :: IntSeqTree [Integer]
intSeqTree = fix $ create []
  where create p x = IntSeqTree p $ fmap (extend x) nats
        extend x n = case span (>n) (val x) of
                       ([], p) -> fix $ create (n:p)
                       (m, p)  -> foldr step intSeqTree (m ++ n:p)

instance Functor IntSeqTree where
  fmap f (IntSeqTree a t) = IntSeqTree (f a) (fmap (fmap f) t)
```

In my use case I have hundreds or thousands of similar integer sequences (of length few hundred entries) that are generated incrementally. So for me this way is cheaper than sorting the sequences before looking up the function value (which I will access by using fmap on intSeqTree).

Answer (score 2):

How about just defining `g_m' = g_m . sort`, i.e. you simply sort the input list first before calling your memoized function?

I have a feeling this is the best you can do since if you want your memoized graph to consist of only sorted paths someone is going to have to look at all of the elements of the list before constructing the path.

Depending on what your input lists look like it might be helpful to transform them in a way which makes the trees branch less. For instance, you might try sorting and taking differences:

```
original input list:   [8,3,14,8,5]
sorted:                [3,3,8,8,14]
diffed:                [3,0,5,0,6] -- use this as the key
```

The transformation is a bijection, and the trees branch less because there are smaller numbers involved.

Comment: I'd like to avoid walking the graph from the root for many integers **a** for a fixed integer list **as** to get **f (a:as)** as the lists can become quite long.

Comment: So it seems you want two things: 1) after computing `f([2..100])` you'll be computing `f([1..100])` but you don't want to walk the graph again to retrieve the cached value of `f([2..100])`. And 2) After computing `f([1,5])` you want `f([5,1])` to find that previously computed value. Is that right?

Comment: Yes! Maybe I should have put the 2nd paragraph of my question at the end??

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bit different approach.
There is a trick in proof that a finite product of countable sets is countable:

We can map the sequence `[a1, ..., an]` to `Nat` by `product . zipWith (^) primes`: `2 ^ a1 * 3 ^ a2 * 5 ^ a3 * ... * primen ^ an`.

To avoid problems with sequences with zero at the end, we can increase the last index.

As the sequence is ordered, we can exploit the property as [user5402](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27824479/1308058) mentioned.

The benefit of using the tree, is that you can increase branching to speed-up traversal. OTOH prime trick could make indexes quite big, but hopefully some tree paths will just be unexplored (remain as thunks).

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

-- Modified from Kmett's answer:
data Tree a = Tree a (Tree a) (Tree a) (Tree a) (Tree a)
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Tree x a b c d) = Tree (f x) (fmap f a) (fmap f b) (fmap f c) (fmap f d)

index :: Tree a -> Integer -> a
index (Tree x _ _ _ _) 0 = x
index (Tree _ a b c d) n = case (n - 1) `divMod` 4 of
  (q,0) -> index a q
  (q,1) -> index b q
  (q,2) -> index c q
  (q,3) -> index d q

nats :: Tree Integer
nats = go 0 1
    where
        go !n !s = Tree n (go a s') (go b s') (go c s') (go d s')
            where
                a = n + s
                b = a + s
                c = b + s
                d = c + s
                s' = s * 4

toList :: Tree a -> [a]
toList as = map (index as) [0..]

-- Primes -- https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers
-- Generation and factorisation could be done much better
minus (x:xs) (y:ys) = case (compare x y) of
           LT -> x : minus  xs  (y:ys)
           EQ ->     minus  xs     ys
           GT ->     minus (x:xs)  ys
minus  xs     _     = xs

primes = 2 : sieve [3..] primes
  where
    sieve xs (p:ps) | q <- p*p , (h,t) <- span (< q) xs =
                   h ++ sieve (t `minus` [q, q+p..]) ps

addToLast :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
addToLast [] = []
addToLast [x] = [x + 1]
addToLast (x:xs) = x : addToLast xs

subFromLast :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
subFromLast [] = []
subFromLast [x] = [x - 1]
subFromLast (x:xs) = x : subFromLast xs

addSubProp :: [NonNegative Integer] -> Property
addSubProp xs = xs' === subFromLast (addToLast xs')
  where xs' = map getNonNegative xs

-- Trick from user5402 answer
toDiffList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
toDiffList = toDiffList' 0
  where toDiffList' _ [] = []
        toDiffList' p (x:xs) = x - p : toDiffList' x xs

fromDiffList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
fromDiffList = fromDiffList' 0
  where fromDiffList' _ [] = []
        fromDiffList' p (x:xs) = p + x : fromDiffList' (x + p) xs

diffProp :: [Integer] -> Property
diffProp xs = xs === fromDiffList (toDiffList xs)

listToInteger :: [Integer] -> Integer
listToInteger = product . zipWith (^) primes . addToLast

integerToList :: Integer -> [Integer]
integerToList = subFromLast . impl primes 0
  where impl _      _ 0 = []
        impl _      0 1 = []
        impl _      k 1 = [k]
        impl (p:ps) k n = case n `divMod` p of
                            (n', 0) -> impl (p:ps) (k + 1) n'
                            (_,  _) -> k : impl ps 0 n

listProp :: [NonNegative Integer] -> Property
listProp xs = xs' === integerToList (listToInteger xs')
  where xs' = map getNonNegative xs

toIndex :: [Integer] -> Integer
toIndex = listToInteger . toDiffList

fromIndex :: Integer -> [Integer]
fromIndex = fromDiffList . integerToList

-- [1,0] /= [0]
-- Decreasing sequence!
doesntHold :: [NonNegative Integer] -> Property
doesntHold xs = xs' === fromIndex (toIndex xs')
  where xs' = map getNonNegative xs

holds :: [NonNegative Integer] -> Property
holds xs = xs' === fromIndex (toIndex xs')
  where xs' = sort $ map getNonNegative xs

g :: ([Integer] -> Integer) -> [Integer] -> Integer
g mg = g' . sort
  where g' [] = 0
        g' (x:xs)  = x + sum (map mg $ tails xs)

g_tree :: Tree Integer
g_tree = fmap (g faster_g' . fromIndex) nats

faster_g' :: [Integer] -> Integer
faster_g' = index g_tree . toIndex

faster_g = faster_g' . sort
```

On my machine `fix g [1..22]` feels slow, when `faster_g [1..40]` is still blazing fast.

---

*Addition*: **if** we have bounded set (with indexes *0..n-1*) , we can encode it as: `a0 * n^0 + a1 * n^1 ...`.

We can encode any `Integer` as binary list, e.g. `11` is `[1, 1, 0, 1]` (least bit first).
Then if we separate integers in the list with `2`, we get sequence of bounded values.

As bonus we can take the sequence of *0, 1, 2* digits and *compress* it to binary using e.g. Huffman encoding, as 2 is much rarer than 0 or 1. But this might be overkill.

With this trick, indexes stay much smaller and the space probably is better packed.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

-- From Kment's answer:
import Data.Function (fix)
import Data.List (sort, tails)
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Test.QuickCheck

{-- Tree definition as before --}

-- 0, 1, 2
newtype N3 = N3 { unN3 :: Integer }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Arbitrary N3 where
  arbitrary = elements $ map N3 [ 0, 1, 2 ]

-- Integer <-> N3
coeffs3 :: [Integer]
coeffs3 = coeffs' 1
  where coeffs' n = n : coeffs' (n * 3)

listToInteger :: [N3] -> Integer
listToInteger = sum . zipWith f coeffs3
  where f n (N3 m) = n * m

listFromInteger :: Integer -> [N3]
listFromInteger 0 = []
listFromInteger n = case n `divMod` 3 of
  (q, m) -> N3 m : listFromInteger q

listProp :: [N3] -> Property
listProp xs = (null xs || last xs /= N3 0) ==> xs === listFromInteger (listToInteger xs)

-- Integer <-> N2

-- 0, 1
newtype N2 = N2 { unN2 :: Integer }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

coeffs2 :: [Integer]
coeffs2 = coeffs' 1
  where coeffs' n = n : coeffs' (n * 2)

integerToBin :: Integer -> [N2]
integerToBin 0 = []
integerToBin n = case n `divMod` 2 of
  (q, m) -> N2 m : integerToBin q

integerFromBin :: [N2] -> Integer
integerFromBin = sum . zipWith f coeffs2
  where f n (N2 m) = n * m

binProp :: NonNegative Integer -> Property
binProp (NonNegative n) = n === integerFromBin (integerToBin n)

-- unsafe!
n3ton2 :: N3 -> N2
n3ton2 = N2 . unN3

n2ton3 :: N2 -> N3
n2ton3 = N3 . unN2

-- [Integer] <-> [N3]
integerListToN3List :: [Integer] -> [N3]
integerListToN3List = concatMap (++ [N3 2]) . map (map n2ton3 . integerToBin)

integerListFromN3List :: [N3] -> [Integer]
integerListFromN3List = init . map (integerFromBin . map n3ton2) . splitOn [N3 2]

n3ListProp :: [NonNegative Integer] -> Property
n3ListProp xs = xs' === integerListFromN3List (integerListToN3List xs')
  where xs' = map getNonNegative xs

-- Trick from user5402 answer
-- Integer <-> Sorted Integer
toDiffList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
toDiffList = toDiffList' 0
  where toDiffList' _ [] = []
        toDiffList' p (x:xs) = x - p : toDiffList' x xs

fromDiffList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
fromDiffList = fromDiffList' 0
  where fromDiffList' _ [] = []
        fromDiffList' p (x:xs) = p + x : fromDiffList' (x + p) xs

diffProp :: [Integer] -> Property
diffProp xs = xs === fromDiffList (toDiffList xs)

---

toIndex :: [Integer] -> Integer
toIndex = listToInteger . integerListToN3List . toDiffList

fromIndex :: Integer -> [Integer]
fromIndex = fromDiffList . integerListFromN3List . listFromInteger

-- [1,0] /= [0]
-- Decreasing sequence! doesn't terminate in this case
doesntHold :: [NonNegative Integer] -> Property
doesntHold xs = xs' === fromIndex (toIndex xs')
  where xs' = map getNonNegative xs

holds :: [NonNegative Integer] -> Property
holds xs = xs' === fromIndex (toIndex xs')
  where xs' = sort $ map getNonNegative xs

g :: ([Integer] -> Integer) -> [Integer] -> Integer
g mg = g' . sort
  where g' [] = 0
        g' (x:xs)  = x + sum (map mg $ tails xs)

g_tree :: Tree Integer
g_tree = fmap (g faster_g' . fromIndex) nats

faster_g' :: [Integer] -> Integer
faster_g' = index g_tree . toIndex

faster_g = faster_g' . sort
```

---

*Second addition:*

I quickly benchmarked graph and binary sequence approach for my `g` with:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- read . head <$> getArgs
  print $ faster_g [100, 110..n]
```

And the results are:

```
% time ./IntegerMemo 1000
1225560638892526472150132981770
./IntegerMemo 1000  0.19s user 0.01s system 98% cpu 0.200 total
% time ./IntegerMemo 2000
3122858113354873680008305238045814042010921833620857170165770
./IntegerMemo 2000  1.83s user 0.05s system 99% cpu 1.888 total
% time ./IntegerMemo 2500
4399449191298176980662410776849867104410434903220291205722799441218623242250
./IntegerMemo 2500  3.74s user 0.09s system 99% cpu 3.852 total
% time ./IntegerMemo 3000    
5947985907461048240178371687835977247601455563536278700587949163642187584269899171375349770
./IntegerMemo 3000  6.66s user 0.13s system 99% cpu 6.830 total

% time ./IntegerMemoGrap 1000 
1225560638892526472150132981770
./IntegerMemoGrap 1000  0.10s user 0.01s system 97% cpu 0.113 total
% time ./IntegerMemoGrap 2000
3122858113354873680008305238045814042010921833620857170165770
./IntegerMemoGrap 2000  0.97s user 0.04s system 98% cpu 1.028 total
% time ./IntegerMemoGrap 2500
4399449191298176980662410776849867104410434903220291205722799441218623242250
./IntegerMemoGrap 2500  2.11s user 0.08s system 99% cpu 2.202 total
% time ./IntegerMemoGrap 3000 
5947985907461048240178371687835977247601455563536278700587949163642187584269899171375349770
./IntegerMemoGrap 3000  3.33s user 0.09s system 99% cpu 3.452 total
```

Looks like that graph version is faster by constant factor of **2**. But they seem to have same time complexity :)

Comment: Did you mean to write 2^a1*3^a2*5^a3... instead? My lists will have few thousands of entries with values up to few thousand, so I didn't want to encode lists of integers as (quite long) integers. PS: Thanks for the long answer, checking might take a day...

Comment: Ah true, `primen^an`. If you have relatively small deltas between entries, the result integer won't grow "large". `faster_g [100,120..2000]` performs relatively fast still.

**If** you know that values are bounded from the top as well, you can use `a1 + a2 * N + a3 * N * N + ...` encoding, which is much more *terse*.

Comment: @j.p. Seems that your `Graph` version is twice as fast as my binary trick. Not to say `Graph` one is much leaner!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my problem is solved by simply replacing `intSeq` in the definition of `g_graph` by a monotone version:

```
-- replace vertexes for non-monotone integer lists by the according monotone one
monoIntSeq :: Graph [Integer]
monoIntSeq = f intSeq
  where f (Graph as t) | as == sort as = Graph as $ fmap f t
                       | otherwise     = fetch monIntSeq $ sort as

-- extract the subgraph after following the given labels
fetch :: Graph a -> [Integer] -> Graph a
fetch g [] = g
fetch (Graph _ t) (x:xs) = fetch (index t x) xs

g_graph :: Graph (StrictPair Integer [Integer])
g_graph = fmap (g g_m) monoIntSeq
```

Many thanks to all (especially user5402 and Oleg) for the help!

---

**Edit:** I still have the problem that the memory consumption is to high for my typical use case which can be described by following a path like this:

```
p :: [Integer]
p = map f [1..]
  where f n | n `mod` 6 == 0 = n `div` 6
            | n `mod` 3 == 0 = n `div` 3
            | n `mod` 2 == 0 = n `div` 2
            | otherwise      = n
```

A slight improvement is to define the monotone integer sequences directly like this:

```
-- extract the subgraph after following the given labels (right to left)
fetch :: Graph a -> [Integer] -> Graph a
fetch = foldl' step
  where step (Graph _ t) n = index t n

-- walk the graph following the given labels (right to left)
walk :: Graph a -> [Integer] -> a
walk g ns = a
  where Graph a _ = fetch g ns

-- all monotone falling integer sequences
monoIntSeqs :: Graph [Integer]
monoIntSeqs = Graph [] $ fmap (flip f monoIntSeqs) nats
  where f n (Graph ns t) | null ns      = Graph (n:ns) $ fmap (f n) t
                         | n >= head ns = Graph (n:ns) $ fmap (f n) t
                         | otherwise    = fetch monoIntSeqs (insert' n ns)
        insert' = insertBy (comparing Down)
```

But at the end I might just use the original integer sequences without identification, identify nodes now and then explicitly and avoid keeping a reference to g_graph etc to let the garbage collection clean up as the program proceeds.