# Function complexity from exponential to linear

Tags: haskell, time-complexity

I have following function which has exponential complexity:

```
c :: Integer -> Integer
c n 
   | n <= 4 = n + 10
   | otherwise = c (n-1) + 2 * (c (n-4))
```

I'm struggling to make the complexity of this function to linear.

`c x` shoud terminate even if 1000 < x < 100000

Comment: Take a look at the [canonical Fibonacci implementation](https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence#Canonical_zipWith_implementation).

Comment: You can just tabulate the values for that function starting from `0` and replace the recursive calls with lookups over this table. Using a simple list this becomes O(n^2). As suggested by n.m. this can then evolve in a way that avoids the O(n) lookups and achieve O(n) total complexity.

Comment: This is a semi-duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208258/memoization-in-haskell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two ways to solve this problem linearly in time.

### Using intermediate memory

```
c1 :: Integer -> Integer
c1 n 
  | n <= 4 = n + 10
  | otherwise = go n (map c1 [4,3,2,1])
  where
    go 4 (a:_) = a 
    go n [a,b,c,d] = go (n-1) [a + 2*d, a, b, c]
```

Here we use four intermediate registers and shift them while `go`ing through the cycle. We could use tuple `(a, b, c, d)` instead of a list, but it is more handy to start with mapping here.

This solution is constant in space and linear in time.

### Memoization (codata generation)

```
c2 :: Integer -> Integer
c2 n
  | n <= 4 = n + 10
  | otherwise = results !! fromInteger (n - 1)
  where
    results = [11..14] ++ zipWith f (drop 3 results) results 
    f a b = a + 2*b
```

Here we use the laziness of Haskell (normal evaluation strategy + memoization). The infinite list `results`  generates values one-by-one on demand. It is used as data by `c2` function which just requests the generator for `n`-th number, and in self-definition. At the same time this data does not exist until it is needed. Such sort of data is called *codata* and it is rather common in Haskell.

This solution is linear in space and time.

Both solutions handle negative numbers and large positive numbers.

Comment: Another approach is to express the recurrence in terms of matrix multiplication. That is, given a column vector of four successive elements of the sequence, you can multiply them on the left by a fixed matrix to get the next four elements of the sequence. `m * m * m * ... * v`. But this is just `m ^ k * v`, and using exponentiation by squaring (`stimesMonoid`), this calculation is much more efficient, in practice, than `c1`.

Comment: @dfeuer, That's indeed excellent mathematical approach for recurrent formulas, both elegant and practical. In general non-numeric (or nonlinear ) cases iterative cycles or memorization  are still useful.