# haskell how to archive memorize

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve #15 from Project Euler, this is my first solution
    import Data.List

```
type Location = (Int,Int)

boardX = 20
boardY = 20

stepBack :: Location -> [Location]
stepBack (x,y) = [(x-1,y), (x,y-1)]

legalStep :: Location -> Bool
legalStep (x,y) = x >= 0 && y >= 0

iteractStep :: Int -> [[Location]]
iteractStep 0 = [[(boardX, boardY)]]
iteractStep n = [x:y|y <- iteractStep (n-1), x<- stepBack (head y),       legalStep x]

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ length $ iteractStep (boardX + boardY)
```

this is very slow, i find there are so many sub-problem re-computed, i try to memorize sub-problem answer, then i found this example:

```
  memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
  memoized_fib = (map fib [0 ..] !!)
    where fib 0 = 0
          fib 1 = 1
          fib n = memoized_fib (n-2) + memoized_fib (n-1)
```

i try it in ghci, i found it actually memorize sub-problem result, i can't understand how this code can memorize result, it looks like

```
map fib [0 ..]
```

is global, but i think it is method scope (only exists at every method call), why it can memorize result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memoization in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208258/memoization-in-haskell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memoized_fib` works because it initially just creates a `thunk` out of `map fib [0..]` (this is laziness, call-by-need). On subsequent calls more and more `fib` values in the list are calculated and at the same time each call looks up a `fib` value by indexing into the list (!!).

Without the list each call to `fib` would have made another two calls to `fib` which again would make two calls, etc. In algorithmic terms this changes `fib` from O(n^2) to O(n).

Without having looked at the Project Euler problem I suggest you try with another data structure first. In your case you should probably try with [vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) or perhaps [array](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array). Those are both much faster than list which you are currently using and which is actually a linked list.

You might also gain a little bit from changing your board representation to `board :: [Int]`. We intuitively think of a board as having two dimensions, but it's quite easy to implement as a list rather than list of lists. (This I remember from a chapter in [PAIP](http://norvig.com/paip.html))

For other problems keep [containers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) and [unordered-containers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) in mind.

Comment: got it, memoized_fib just like fibs = 1:1: zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs), final result is a list. i have another problem, i only use fmap and head operation on list, why vector fast than list?

Comment: For `head` I don't think it makes a large, if any difference. AFAIK a vector keeps elements next to each other in memory where a linked list has pointers between elements, so any traversal e.g. `fmap` should be much faster on a `vector`.

Comment: Just came across a good explanation of the difference in efficiency between lists and vectors at [School of Haskell](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/commercial/content/vector#efficiency)