# Haskell: memoization of recursion

Tags: haskell, memoization

if I have the following function:

```
go xxs t i
  | t == 0         = 1
  | t < 0          = 0
  | i < 0          = 0
  | t < (xxs !! i) = go xxs t (i-1)
  | otherwise      = go xxs (t - (xxs !! i)) (i-1) + go xxs t (i-1)
```

what is the best way to memoize the results? I can't seem to get my head how to store a dynamic set of tuples and update and return the value at the same time.

The equivalent of what I am trying to do in python would be:

```
def go(xxs, t , i, m):
  k = (t,i)
  if  k in m:      # check if value for this pair is already in dictionary 
      return m[k]
  if t == 0:
      return 1
  elif t < 0:
      return 0
  elif i < 0:
      return 0
  elif t < xxs[i]:
      val = go(xxs, t, i-1,m)  
  else:
      val = (go(xxs, total - xxs[i]), i-1,m) + go(xxs, t, i-1,m)
  m[k] = val  # store the new value in dictionary before returning it
  return val
```

EDIT: I think this is somewhat different to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208258). The function in question there has a linear progression and you can index the results with a list `[1..]`. In this case, my Keys `(t,i)` are not necessarily in order or incremental. for example I could end up with an set of keys that are

`[(9,1),(8,2),(7,4),(6,4),(5,5),(4,6),(3,6),(2,7),(1,8),(0,10)]`

Comment: I think two days ago there was somebody that asked more or less the very same question.

Comment: The "best" way is to use one of the packages that provide memoization.  Consider MemoTrie and monad-memo.  If you want to role your own it can be fun and instructive to do with a State monad.  If you want your algorithm to perform better then consider ditching the use of `(!!)` which is itself O(N) and incurred multiple times - use a vector or array if you must perform random access.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please see my edit

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson is there no easier way to roll your own. The other examples on stack overflow seem to involve really complicated solutions to something that seems to be me should be easy... if you know how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there no easier way to roll your own [memoization?]

Easier than what? A state monad is really easy and if you are used to thinking imperatively then it should also be intuitive.

The full, inlined, version that uses a vector instead of the list is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}
import Control.Monad.Trans.State as S
import Data.Vector as V
import Data.Map.Strict as M

goGood :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int
goGood xs t0 i0 =
    let v = V.fromList xs
    in evalState (explicitMemo v t0 i0) mempty
 where
 explicitMemo :: Vector Int -> Int -> Int -> State (Map (Int,Int) Int) Int
 explicitMemo v t i = do
    m <- M.lookup (t,i) <$> get
    case m of
        Nothing ->
         do res <- if | t == 0          -> pure 1
                      | t < 0           -> pure 0
                      | i < 0           -> pure 0
                      | t < (v V.! i)   -> explicitMemo v t (i-1)
                      | otherwise       -> (+) <$> explicitMemo v (t - (v V.! i)) (i-1) <*> explicitMemo v t
 (i-1)
            S.modify (M.insert (t,i) res)
            pure res
        Just r  -> pure r
```

That is, we look up in a map if we've already computed the result. If so, return the result. If not, compute and store the result before returning it.

We can clean this up a lot with just a couple helper functions:

```
prettyMemo :: Vector Int -> Int -> Int -> State (Map (Int,Int) Int) Int
prettyMemo v t i = cachedReturn =<< cachedEval (
            if | t == 0          -> pure 1
               | t < 0           -> pure 0
               | i < 0           -> pure 0
               | t < (v V.! i)   -> prettyMemo v t (i-1)
               | otherwise       ->
                   (+) <$> prettyMemo v (t - (v V.! i)) (i-1)
                       <*> prettyMemo v t (i-1)
            )
 where
 key = (t,i)
 -- Lookup value in cache and return it
 cachedReturn res = S.modify (M.insert key res) >> pure res

 -- Use cached value or run the operation
 cachedEval oper = maybe oper pure =<< (M.lookup key <$> get)
```

Now our map lookup and map update are in some simple (to the experienced Haskell developer) helper functions that wrap the entire computation.  A small difference here is we update the map regardless of if the computation was cached at some minor computational cost.

We can make this even cleaner by dropping the monad (see the linked related questions).  There is a popular package (MemoTrie) that handles the guts for you:

```
memoTrieVersion :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int
memoTrieVersion xs = go
 where
 v = V.fromList xs
 go t i | t == 0 = 1
        | t < 0  = 0
        | i < 0  = 0
        | t < v V.! i = memo2 go t (i-1)
        | otherwise   = memo2 go (t - (v V.! i)) (i-1) + memo2 go t (i-1)
```

If you like the monadic style you could always use the `monad-memo` package.

EDIT: A mostly-direct translation of your Python code to Haskell shows an important difference is the immutability of the variables.  In your `otherwise` (or `else`) case you use `go` twice and implicitly one invocation will update the cache (`m`) that the second call uses, thus saving computation in a memoizing manner.  In Haskell if you're avoiding monads and lazy evaluation to recursively define a vector (which can be quite powerful) then the simplest solution left is to explicitly pass your map (dictionary) around:

```
import Data.Vector as V
import Data.Map as M

goWrapped :: Vector Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
goWrapped xxs t i = fst $ goPythonVersion xxs t i mempty

goPythonVersion :: Vector Int -> Int -> Int -> Map (Int,Int) Int -> (Int,Map (Int,Int) Int)
goPythonVersion xxs t i m =
  let k = (t,i)
  in case M.lookup k m of -- if  k in m:
    Just r -> (r,m)       --     return m[k]
    Nothing ->
      let (res,m') | t == 0 = (1,m)
                   | t  < 0 = (0,m)
                   | i  < 0 = (0,m)
                   | t  < xxs V.! i = goPythonVersion xxs t (i-1) m
                   | otherwise  =
                      let (r1,m1) = goPythonVersion xxs (t - (xxs V.! i)) (i-1) m
                          (r2,m2) = goPythonVersion xxs t (i-1) m1
                      in (r1 + r2, m2)
      in (res, M.insert k res m')
```

And while this version is a decent translation of the Python I'd rather see a more idiomatic solution such as the below.  Notice we bind a variable to the resulting computation (named "computed" for the Int and the updated map) but thanks to lazy evaluation not much work is done unless the cache doesn't yield a result.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
goMoreIdiomatic:: Vector Int -> Int -> Int -> Map (Int,Int) Int -> (Int,Map (Int,Int) Int)
goMoreIdiomatic xxs t i m =
  let cached = M.lookup (t,i) m
      ~(comp, M.insert (t,i) comp -> m')
        | t == 0 = (1,m)
        | t  < 0 = (0,m)
        | i  < 0 = (0,m)
        | t  < xxs V.! i = goPythonVersion xxs t (i-1) m
        | otherwise  =
           let (r1,m1) = goPythonVersion xxs (t - (xxs V.! i)) (i-1) m
               (r2,m2) = goPythonVersion xxs t (i-1) m1
           in (r1 + r2, m2)
    in maybe (comp,m') (,m) cached
```

Comment: Thank you for this. "easier than what?", well I meant as easy as the 50 or so character amendments in my python code. The memoization of that code took very little effort. I was hoping that the haskell version would not involve having to melt my brain :). however, What you have post is very helpful and it is exactly what I am looking for in terms of learning. Thanks again

Comment: @matthias Ah I see. I added sort of a translation of your Python code so you can read that and compare.

Comment: amazing, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: in the `memoTrie` version should `v = V.toList xs` be `v = V.FromList xs` also, your `goPythonVersion` doesn't seem t work?

Comment: The `goPythonVersion` ran - did you mean the wrong result? You are adding the last two values in the `else` case and I forgot/discarded the `r1` value (edited).  Warnings via `-Wall` catch these simple mistakes and I should have used them.  Yes, `fromList` (lower case f) is what I meant with the other example.

Comment: I had fixed the last part of the python version. I meant there is no improvement in speed with the memoization (in fact it might be worst) whereas your state examples are instant with massive lists.

Comment: Oh, lol. That's because I never insert the result into the map. What was I thinking yesterday!  There's no match to the python `m[k]=val`. Will edit in a little while.