# Why is it a memoization function?

Tags: haskell

Could someone please explain to me, why the following code is the memoization:

```
fib_mem :: Int -> Integer
fib_mem = (map fib [0..] !!)
where fib 0 = 1
      fib 1 = 1
      fib n = fib_mem (n-2) + fib_mem (n-1)
```

Comment: What do you mean *why*?!

Comment: This function use the memoization technique, where intermediate results are saved and later reused.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking.

Comment: An easier definition would be `let fib :: Int -> Integer; fib = (fib' !!) where fib' = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib' (tail fib')`.

Comment: this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11466284/849891). due to a technicality, I am unable to close it as a dupe now.

Comment: [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209189/849891).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're asking how this memoizes `fib`. `fib` itself is just an ordinary function. The real magic happens in `fib_mem = (map fib [0..] !!)`, which memoizes `fib`. This expression is equivalent to  saying that `fib_mem x = (map fib [0..]) !! x`. Let's break this down to see what it's doing:

- `[0..]` is an infinite list starting `[0,1,2,3,..]` and continuing *ad infinitum*.
- `map fib [0..]` applies `fib` to each element of this list, producing a list where each element is the Fibonacci number corresponding to the index of that element, so e.g. `8` is at index `5`. **This is the importent step**; it memoizes `fib` by applying it to every number, so once the value at a particular index is forced, it does not have to be recalculated.
- Then `!!` is used to get the value back from the list, at the appropriate index.

Comment: I'd say there is also a bit of magic when the "ordinary function" `fib` uses `fib_mem` in its implementation.  Or at least, that's part of the technique.

Comment: @bradrn `it memoizes fib by applying it to every number` why does it memoizes?

Comment: Because once it's applied to one particular number, the compiler knows that that value is at that index in the list, and so can simply look up the value in the list next time. So e.g. if you've requested `fib_mem 5`, the compiler looks up index `5` in the list, which turns out to be the value `fib 5`, which it calculates. Next time you request `fib 5`, the compiler looks up the index `5` in the list again, however the list is now stored not as `[.., fib 5, ...]` but instead as `[..., 8, ...]`, so it can simply look up the previously-calculated value.

Answer (score 0):

In case you meant  "***why*** is it a *memoizing* function", [the answer is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677772/at-the-top-level-results-will-persist-in-memory/54678333#comment96153886_54678333), *because* it is a [CAF (constant applicative form)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization#Memoising_CAFS) and [has a monomorphic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54675020/why-it-does-not-show-as-evaluated#comment96146739_54675020).