# At the top level, results will persist in memory

Tags: haskell

I am working through the book https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/haskell-high-performance-programming and at moment, I am trying to understand the memoization.

It shows the following memoization function:

```
fib_mem :: Int -> Integer
fib_mem = (map fib [0..] !!)
where fib 0 = 1
      fib 1 = 1
      fib n = fib_mem (n-2) + fib_mem (n-1)
```

In the book, it says:

> So if fib_mem is defined at the top level, the results will persist in
>   memory over the lifetime of the programm itself!

What does it mean, define at the top level?

Comment: I believe it means it's in global scope, not inside a `let` or `where` clause or similar local expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Top-level" is a synonym for ["REPL"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/read-eval-print-loop/info), or if you use a source code file, it's its most outer scope -- it's global scope.

Traditionally, in Lisp, loading source code file was as if you executed its top level statements by typing them at the REPL one by one.

see also: [How is this fibonacci-function memoized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11466284/849891)

Comment: FWIW I believe that for `fib_mem` to be memoized, it must be a CAF in addition to being a top-level declaration. So the book was not as precise as perhaps it could have been. https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization#Memoising_CAFS

Comment: @ReinHenrichs you are absolutely right. with these kinds of what looks like almost self-published books, it's always a gamble. --- It must also have a monomorhic type, I believe, as is discussed on the entry I linked IIRC.

Comment: Packt is basically a book mill.