# Generalized recursion doesn't work for Haskell memoization

Tags: haskell, memoization

After reading several sources, I came up with the following `memo` function for memoization in Haskell with "generalized recursion." But it doesn't work. Why?!

```hs
fib f 0 = 1
fib f 1 = 1
fib f n = fib f (n - 1) + fib f (n - 2)

memo f n = fList !! n
  where fList = map (f (fList !!)) [0..]
```

Recursive run w/o memoization

```hs
λ> fix fib 30
1346269
(1.65 secs, 962,135,992 bytes)
```

It takes the same time as a "memoized" version:

```hs
λ> memo fib 30
1346269
(1.62 secs, 962,141,192 bytes)
```

However, the following works:

```hs
fibMemoDirect n = fibList !! n
  where fibList = map fib [0..]
        fib 0 = 1
        fib 1 = 1
        fib n = fibList !! (n - 1) + fibList !! (n - 2)
```

```hs
λ> fibMemoDirect 30
1346269
(0.01 secs, 93,728 bytes)
```

Why doesn't `memo fib` above work as fast as `fibMemoDirect` given that both use CAF?

Sources:

- [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization#Memoization_with_recursion)
- Edward Kmett's [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209189/1060693)

Comment: `!!` is `O(n)` and not like in other languages `O(1)`. I'm not sure that's the only problem though.

Comment: @user1984, yes indeed it's sub-optimal. But `fibMemoDirect` also uses `!!` and works ~200 times faster.

Comment: To make sure they differ asymptotically and the difference isn't just some constant, I suggest to run the code for (30 * 5) and (30 * 10) and see how the times change.

Comment: `fibMemoDirect 3000` completes in 0.13 seconds. `memo fib 3000` never completes.

Comment: Your fib function is directly recursive and doesn't use its `f` argument. So you could as well run it without `fix` and you'd get the same result in the same time. That's why replacing `fix` with `memo` makes no difference.

Comment: @sepp2k, oh yes! That's such an embarrassment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost gotten it, but your third line needs to be

```
fib f n = f (n-1) + f (n-2)
```

...or else you're not even using `f` and just writing a normal, recursive, exponential Fibonacci function.